# Query to Find the root of a given node

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Sorry, I know similar questions have been asked lots of time but I am really struggling to make this work

I have a table of jobs, some jobs have child jobs and they can have further child jobs etc (the depth is not constrained).

What I am trying to achieve is to do a select x,y,x from jobs and have the root job returned as a field within the result

I have seen lots of examples for CTEs however these all seem to have the starting point (e.g. 14 in the example below) embedded in the code but this will not work for us or others that materialise the entire table which are too slow

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents( id, parent_id ) 
AS (
  -- get leaf children
  SELECT id, parent_id
  FROM job
  WHERE id = 14

  UNION ALL

  -- get all parents  
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
  FROM parents p
  JOIN job t
  ON p.parent_id = t.id
)
SELECT * from parents
-- WHERE parent_id is null;
```

if the version is important were running 10.10

Comment: Is the problem that your query is too slow, or that your query isn't returning the root node, or both?

Comment: Sorry, using the CTE in PGAdmin I can open the view and see the result but that would be just for job 14, how can I make this work for any job so I can do something like Select * from JobInfo where job_id = 14 and have the root job return in the results?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that root nodes have a `parent_id` of `null`, then you can do this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents( id, parent_id, root_id ) 
AS (
  -- get root nodes
  SELECT id, parent_id, id AS root_id
  FROM job
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  -- get children  
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, p.root_id
  FROM parents p
  JOIN job t
  ON t.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT * from parents
--WHERE parent_id = 14;
```

EDIT: To get the root id of a particular child reasonably fast, you could use this query (assuming the child ID is 14):

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy( id, parent_id ) 
AS (
  -- get child
  SELECT id, parent_id
  FROM job
  WHERE id = 14

  UNION ALL

  -- get parents
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
  FROM hierarchy p
  JOIN job t
  ON t.id = p.parent_id
)
SELECT id AS root_id
FROM hierarchy
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but was erroring on t.root_id, suggested using p.root_id which I tried, but returned no results

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have been `p.root_id`. Do your root nodes have the value `null` for `parent_id`?

Comment: Also, `= null` should be `IS NULL`, I've changed that in the SQL now

Comment: Thanks that now works, however it is quite slow. It seems mad to be asking for all the parents and iterating all the way down, when we know the child can't we walk our way back up?

Comment: CTEs tend to be expensive with hierarchies, as the entire hierarchy needs to be built before filters can be applied. Some good strategies to speed up execution times on selecting against hierarchies are data vaulting the tree on a schedule, or using a parameterised stored proc to select a particular branch.

Comment: @RobertB I updated the answer to provide an alternative way to quickly get the root_id of a known child id

Comment: thanks for the update, how could I use that so I could pass in or join the ID (e.g. 14) to make it re-usable, think I need to wrap it in a function but an pass the starting JOB ID in, but how to do that and then use it, I assume something like

```SELECT JOBS.*, fn_getRootID(job.id) as root from JOBS where id = 14```

Comment: Hi e_i_pi and @madflow thanks to both of you for you assistance, combining both of your responses I have a solution I am now happy with

I have put the CTE in a function 

CREATE FUNCTION get_RootID( id BIGINT)
RETURNS bigint
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
WITH RECURSIVE parents( id, parent_id ) ...

This then lets me use it in a select

SELECT *, get_rootid(j.id) as root_id
from Jobs j
where j.id = 195922

Only takes 56ms too!

Many thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe appending the complete `path` for each job will already suffice?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qpBBNRP8pTAyXgKuxdanzw/0

```
CREATE TABLE job(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    parent_id INT
);

INSERT INTO job VALUES (1, null), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, null), (6, 5);
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents( id, parent_id ) 
AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY [ id ] AS path
  FROM job
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id,  array_append(p.path, t.id) as path
  FROM parents p
  JOIN job t
  ON t.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT * from parents
-- SELECT * from parents WHERE id=4
ORDER BY path ASC;
```

Another approach could be to use a function that accepts a `job` row and calculates the root job (highly experimental).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION root_job(_job job) RETURNS RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE 
_current_job job;
BEGIN
    _current_job := _job;

    WHILE _current_job.parent_id IS NOT NULL LOOP
        SELECT * FROM job WHERE job.id=_current_job.parent_id INTO _current_job;
    END LOOP ; 

    RETURN _current_job;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT root_job(job) FROM job WHERE id=4;
```

Comment: I will give it a try, from what I have read though CTE's will be materialised before they are filtered so this would mean, all 1.2 Million rows would have their paths built before being reduced the 1 row in question. I will give a go and see what the performance is like. Thanks

Comment: In order to know the "path" (hence the root unit) of a child job - you will always have to calculate the complete tree. At least that what I have always been doing. It would be interesting if there are any alternatives. Maybe there is another criterion (queue name?) that could fit in the parent tree query?